# Date picker date and selected date is not matching?

Tags: android, datepicker

[image]

I am using two date picker in my activity and trying to manage the date from picker ... But this is what is happening the date at the picker is not same as the date that i am trying to set ...
The code is :

```
public class SignInAsEmployee extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnFocusChangeListener {
    EditText UserID, et_from, et_to;
    Button showinfo;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_From = 1;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO = 0;
    int day_q, month_q, year_q;
    int day_p, month_p, year_p;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signinas_employee);
        UserID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_employeeId);
        showinfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        et_from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
        et_to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_to);
        showinfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        et_from.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et_to.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String uId = UserID.getText().toString().trim();
        Intent ShowIinfo = new Intent(SignInAsEmployee.this, MainActivity.class);
        ShowIinfo.putExtra("userId", uId);
        startActivity(ShowIinfo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.tv_from:

            if (this.et_from.isFocused()) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_From);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.tv_to:

            if (this.et_to.isFocused()) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO);
            }
            break;

        }

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener from_dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            day_q = selectedDay;
            month_q = selectedMonth + 1;
            year_q = selectedYear;
            et_from.setText(day_q + " - " + month_q + "-" + year_q);
        }
    };

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener to_dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            day_p = selectedDay;
            month_p = selectedMonth + 1;
            year_p = selectedYear;
            et_to.setText(day_p + " - " + month_p + "-" + year_p);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID_From:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, from_dateListener, year_q,
                    month_q, day_q);

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID_TO:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, to_dateListener, year_p, month_p,
                    day_p);

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your code you are doing wrong here in both `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`

```
month_q = selectedMonth + 1;
```

It should be `month_q = selectedMonth;` ... I'm not sure but you can try...

Comment: No Bro this month_q = selectedMonth + 1; is used to set the date accurately otherwise if you select 11 as month it will show you 10 ... I know this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

The initial day, month and year values you pass to `DatePickerDialog` constructor are not initialized and are in a range not really supported by the widget. You should supply reasonable defaults, such as those from `Calendar.getInstance()` i.e. current date.